# update XML string using sed

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have an XML file similar like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csw:GetRecordByIdResponse xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2">
  <xmlns:gmi="http://sdi.eurac.edu/metadata/iso19139-2/schema/gmi" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork" gco:isoType="gmd:MD_Metadata">
    <gmd:onLine>
                  <gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
                    <gmd:linkage>
                      <gmd:URL>http://server.test.it/geoserver/test_product/wms?SERVICE=WMS&amp;TIME=2018-06-14T10:59:00Z&amp;</gmd:URL>
                    </gmd:linkage>
                    <gmd:protocol>
                      <gco:CharacterString>OGC:WMS-1.1.1-http-get-map</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:protocol>
                    <gmd:name>
                      <gco:CharacterString>test_product:test_product</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:name>
                    <gmd:description>
                      <gco:CharacterString>test_product:test_product</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:description>
                  </gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
    </gmd:onLine>
</csw>
```

I would like to substitute the content of the  tag with the following:

*http://server.test.it/geoserver/test_product/wms?SERVICE=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test_product:test_product&styles=&bbox=140442.2309,3739661.3694,1330442.2309,2564661.3694&width=768&height=576&srs=EPSG:32632&format=application/openlayers&TIME=2018-06-14T10:59:00Z&amp;*

I used to use the `sed` command in bash:

```
correct_url='http://server.test.it/geoserver/test_product/wms?SERVICE=WMS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=GetMap&amp;layers=test_product:test_product&amp;styles=&amp;bbox=140442.2309,3739661.3694,1330442.2309,2564661.3694&amp;width=768&amp;height=576&amp;srs=EPSG:32632&amp;format=application/openlayers&amp;TIME=2018-06-14T10:59:00Z&amp;'
sed -i 's/<gmd:URL>\(.*\)<\/gmd:URL>/<gmd:URL>'"${correct_url}"'<\/gmd:URL>/' xml_file.xml
```

It gives me an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 52: unknown option to `s'

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

using the suggestion of @rubystallion I tried to escape all the special characters:

```
correct_url='http://server.test.it/geoserver/test_product/wms?SERVICE=WMS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=GetMap&amp;layers=test_product:test_product&amp;styles=&amp;bbox=140442.2309,3739661.3694,1330442.2309,2564661.3694&amp;width=768&amp;height=576&amp;srs=EPSG:32632&amp;format=application/openlayers&amp;TIME=2018-06-14T10:59:00Z&amp;'
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url//\//\\\/}"
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url_escaped//&/\\&}"
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url_escaped/\?/\?}"
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url_escaped/\?/\?}"
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url_escaped//\;/\;}"
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url_escaped//\=/\=}"

sed -i 's/<gmd:URL>\(.*\)<\/gmd:URL>/<gmd:URL>'"${correct_url_escaped}"'<\/gmd:URL>/' xml_file.xml
```

But I'm still getting error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unknown option to `s'

Am I still missing something??

Comment: Don't use `sed` to modify XML; instead, use an XML-aware tool.

Comment: Your XML is not valid: `xmllint` returns many `namespace error : Namespace prefix gmd on ... is not defined`.

Comment: @choroba I adde the namespaces. I forgot to write them

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus something like
_xmlstarlet ed -u "//gmd:url" -v $correct_url xml_file.xml_ ?

Comment: @sylar_80, you'd probably need to declare your namespace, as in `xmlstarlet ed -N gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" -u '//gmd:url' -v "$correct_url"` to make it work, but something very much like that, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL has special characters in it, and you are substituting the URL into the executed command. If you place an `echo` in front of your `sed` command line, you'll see what is actually executed, which clearly isn't going to be a valid `sed` command.

You need to escape the URL, or just *not* place it directly into your `sed` command. You can achieve the latter by using the [e](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) flag, which replaces the matched text with the result of an executed command. Like this:

```
url="http://x:y@www.a.com/foo?a=b&c=d" sed -r -i 's/(\s*)<gmd:URL>(.*)<\/gmd:URL>/echo "\1<gmd:URL>$url<\/gmd:URL>"/e' xml_file.xml
```

Note, you should be cautious about using the `e` flag; because you are executing something there are potential security issues.

Also please heed generally good advice about using a XML editing tool to edit XML (in one off simple jobs like this, IMO it's fine to use `sed` if it's the quickest way to get it done ...).

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have mentioned you can write more maintainable scripts and avoid making errors by using XML-aware tools, but let me show you why your code doesn't work:

Bash substitutes variables in strings with their contents before executing commands, so `/` will be parsed as a delimiter by sed and `&` will be parsed as the whole match in the substitution string. If you escape special characters correctly, then your command will work as intended:

```
correct_url='http://server.test.it/geoserver/test_product/wms?SERVICE=WMS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=GetMap&amp;layers=test_product:test_product&amp;styles=&amp;bbox=140442.2309,3739661.3694,1330442.2309,2564661.3694&amp;width=768&amp;height=576&amp;srs=EPSG:32632&amp;format=application/openlayers&amp;TIME=2018-06-14T10:59:00Z&amp;'
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url//\//\\\/}"
correct_url_escaped="${correct_url_escaped//&/\\&}"

token='http://server.test.it/geoserver/test_product/wms?SERVICE=WMS&amp;TIME=2018-06-14T10:59:00Z&amp;'

sed -i 's/<gmd:URL>\(.*\)<\/gmd:URL>/<gmd:URL>'"${correct_url_escaped}"'<\/gmd:URL>/' xml_file.xml
```

Also, please make sure that your commands compile as described in the question next time. You forgot to put quotes around the variables.

Comment: Hi @rubystallion unfortunately I have to say that I still got the same error 
_sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unknown option to `s'_

PS I added the quotes. thanks!

Comment: You don't have to escape the question mark, because you're inserting the URL into the replacement part of the substitution, where question marks don't have a special meaning. If you copy the code I gave verbatim into a file `script.sh` in the same directory as your XML file and then run `bash script.sh`, it should work. To escape special characters, you have to use backslashes, which is what I did in the second and third line using bash substitution.